# Cannot connect to Network - EMERGENCY CALLS ONLY

Tags: recovery-mode, restore, mobile-network, imei

I was trying out some ROMs which I downloaded from needrom.com. At first it was fine. Then when I flashed a particular ROM, I started getting "INVALID IMEI" and could not connect to the network anymore.

Luckily I had a full backup of the phone taken with TWRP. I could not see my backup listed in the TWRP that came with the present ROM. So I flashed the Recovery with which I backed up the phone. Then I could see the Backups listed.

When I tried to restore it, it failed with this error:

```
Unable to mount '/data'
```

I guess the partitioning changed. Anyways, I could restore 'Nvram' alone and the `INVALID IMEI` got replaced by "EMERGENCY CALLS ONLY".

How do I fix this? Can I somehow restore the backup (by fixing Unable to mount `/data`)?

ROM that was working and running currently: http://www.needrom.com/download/ultralight/
ROM that started the trouble: P780_S228_8GB_KK_ROW

Phone: Lenovo P780 8GB.

Comment: You have to call your service provider to reset the phones data connection. For Sprint I had to dial ##72786# ( phone rebooted twice, data [ works after that]). Sorry not more of explaination. @ work.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I've called the operator. The tech guy said he will do something, went on hold, and came back saying that it is a handset issue. Well it really is, because the SIM card works fine on other phones.

Comment: Which service do you use? I'll find out the code for yours. Your data (IMEI, RTN, etc) need to be reset. I just had the SAME issue. No phone calls, only 911. BTW, it is a handset issue because the ROM you used changed those settings. Now they don't match the service provider. Once you reset them, you'll get your phone calls back.

Comment: Wipe data & cache, then flash the ROM that you were using when you made the backup, then restore the backup.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN You should be right. Though I believe what Matthew suggested will solve the issue, I would love to know (and try) what these numbers are, and how to find "the codes" and then reset them. It would be nice if you would write it as an answer. But I don't live in US or EU, and my provider is BSNL India.

Comment: Matthew would be right if you want to use your old rom. I will look for the codes. If I can get what you need to fix your issue, I will then post as an answer.

Comment: I have the IMEI numbers. What other codes do I have to look for?

Comment: Found it, will post answer after work

Answer (score 1):

## Set APN of BSNL Internet Settings:

1. **Settings -> Wireless and Networks -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names (APN)**

Select or click option button
Select “**New APN**”, or edit the existing APN

2. You need to make changes to:

   - *Name* : **bsnl**
   - *APN* : **bsnlnet**
   - *Authentication type* : **None**
   - *APN type* : **internet**
3. **Do Not Change** other fields, **i.e Proxy, Port, User name, Password, Server, MMS proxy and MMS port**. Only edit MCC (Mobile Country Code) and MNC (Mobile Network Code) according to the list provided below. *Note: Following MNC and MCC code are for the users of INDIA only*

**MCC MNC Network State**

- 404 34    BSNL     Haryana
- 404 38    BSNL     Assam
- 404 51    BSNL     Himachal Pradesh
- 404 53    BSNL     Punjab
- 404 54    BSNL     Uttar Pradesh (West)
- 404 55    BSNL     Uttar Pradesh (East)
- 404 57    BSNL     Gujarat
- 404 58    BSNL     Madhya Pradesh
- 404 59    BSNL     Rajasthan
- 404 62    BSNL     Jammu & Kashmir
- 404 64    BSNL     Chennai
- 404 66    BSNL     Maharashtra
- 404 71    BSNL     Karnataka
- 404 72    BSNL     Kerala
- 404 73    BSNL     Andhra Pradesh
- 404 74    BSNL     West Bengal
- 404 75    BSNL     Bihar
- 404 76    BSNL     Orissa
- 404 77    BSNL     North East
- 404 79    BSNL     Andaman Nicobar
- 404 80    BSNL     Tamilnadu
- 404 81    BSNL     Kolkata

  4. Select options, and then save this setting.

---

Information pulled from [Reference Link](http://www.imobileandroid.com/apn-of-bsnl/), please read the lengthy comment section on the link as well.